# TypeError: collatz_seq() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

Tags: python, typeerror

If I don't put any random (I guess) number inside the function (at the end of the code) it shows the above error. I don't understand why it wants any random number as "n". Does anybody know? Thank you.

```
def collatz_seq(n):
    n = int(input("\nEnter a positive integer: "))
    seq = [n]
    while n > 1:
        if (n % 2 == 0):
            n = n / 2
        else:
            n = 3*n + 1
        seq.append(n)
    return seq
print(collatz_seq(15))
```

I tried of course (by accident) to put any random number inside the function and it works properly...But I don't understand why do I have to put a number, and it can't work just by typing print(collatz_seq()).

Comment: In your own words, what does this mean? `def collatz_seq(n)`

Comment: It's a function that needs an "n" (probably) a number, in order to work properly. What I don't understand is, why it works for any random number? In my mind it should've worked only for the "n" the user will type, and I won't have to type manually a random "n" at the end of the code :/

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined it that way?!

```py
def collatz_seq(n):
```

The (n) is **one** parameter. Did you mean

```py
def collatz_seq():
```

?

Comment: I understand that if I don't put the "n" it doesn't work. What I don't understand is why it wants any random number...So I have to put any random number in order to work. I'm a bit confused but I think I understand it better now, thanks for the reply!

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you. Maybe look at your code again. Or at the 'functions' chapter of your book. Or go to sleep and think about it again tomorrow.